# Apache Shiro add URL Exception for Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, servlets, shiro, url-mapping

I am developing a system with Maven + Spring MVC + Apache Shiro. 
Here is my shiro beans

```
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager"> 
    <property name="sessionMode" value="native"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login.jsp"/> 
    <property name="filters">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="authc">
                <bean class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter"/>
            </entry>
        </util:map>
    </property>
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /static/** = anon
            /index.jsp = anon
            /login.jsp = anon
            /user/login = anon
            /user/register = anon 
            /client/face = anon
            /user/logout = logout
            /** = authc
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

After Adding those beans. Now all requests will be redirect to login page.

I wander how to add URL exceptions. Like “/show” will not be asked for login or any other authorization method.

Answer (score 0):

Do your JSPs contain images or other resources that are NOT in /static ?

As far as the question about "/show" you would just anon another 'anon' line.